# Image inside div is not getting drawn at the coordinates set by Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

We are setting the div width and height to image width and height and we set the background image for the div. The background image is getting drawn at the given coordinates. The image inside div should fit in the box of the background image. We calculated the box starting point in the background image (by using http://nicodjimenez.github.io/boxLabel/annotate.html) and we are setting the coordinates of the image of the div accordingly. But the image is not getting drawn properly at the given coordinates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            #board {
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 99999;
                background-color: transparent;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="board">
            <img id="poster" src="//:0">
        </div>

        <script>
            var board = document.getElementById('board');
            var poster = document.getElementById('poster');

            let imgPath = 'url(https://s14.postimg.cc/lyv8mdy9d/billboard3.png)';
            let posterPath = 'url(https://s14.postimg.cc/4yccdq0nl/Iron_Man.jpg';

            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                board.style.width = this.width + "px";
                board.style.height = this.height + "px";
                board.style.left = (window.innerWidth - this.width) + "px";
                board.style.top = (window.innerHeight - this.height - 20) + "px";
                board.style.backgroundImage = imgPath;
                poster.style.left = (parseInt(board.style.left) + 13) + 'px';
                poster.style.top = (parseInt(board.style.top) + 38) + 'px';
                poster.style.width = '158px';
                poster.style.height = '73px';
                poster.src = 'https://s14.postimg.cc/4yccdq0nl/Iron_Man.jpg';
            }

            img.src = 'https://s14.postimg.cc/lyv8mdy9d/billboard3.png';
            function moveLeft()
        {   
            board.style.left = board.style.left || 0;

            if(parseInt(board.style.left) <= -(parseInt(board.style.width)))
            {
                board.style.left = (window.innerWidth - parseInt(board.style.width)) + "px";
            }

            board.style.left = parseInt(board.style.left) - 2 + 'px';
            poster.style.left = (parseInt(board.style.left) + 13) + 'px';
            poster.style.top = (parseInt(board.style.top) + 38) + 'px';
            requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
        }

        moveLeft();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/vyv5p04v/5/

Can anyone please let me know it there is any issue in the code.

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Maybe something you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/vyv5p04v/14/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `poster.style.position = "absolute"` or "relative" inside your load handler. By default positioning is static.

Comment: The image is acutally there (check from inspect element) but not where you want it to be. When you set the img positioning absolute, you no longer need to get the left/top position of the board and offset it. So (parseInt(board.style.left) + 13) + 'px' should become "13px" and poster.style.top = (parseInt(board.style.top) + 38) + 'px' should become "38px"